# How will neo4j jdbc (bolt) handle queries that return a list of nodes?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

In neo4j jdbc (bolt), Node is returned as Map , but if you make a query that returns a list of Nodes, getObject () will return a list of InternalNodes. Entities in this list can not be identified by type instanceof, so reflection will identify the node by type name and you will get the value by calling the method by reflection.You can get the value by doing the following, but is this approach correct? rs is ResultSet.entity is return value of this method.

```
                Object columnObject = rs.getObject(columnName);
                if (columnObject instanceof List<?>){
                    List<Map<String,Object>> objectValue = arrayList();
                    Array columnArray = rs.getArray(columnName);
                    Object[] columnArrayValues = (Object[]) columnArray.getArray();
                    for (int iTmp = 0; iTmp < columnArrayValues.length; iTmp++){
                        Map<String, Object> colArrayItemMap = new HashMap<>();
                        Object colItemObj = columnArrayValues[iTmp];
                        Class colItemClass = colItemObj.getClass();
                        if (colItemClass.getName().equals("org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalNode")){
                            Method asMap = colItemClass.getMethod("asMap");
                            Method getId = colItemClass.getMethod("id");
                            Method getLabels = colItemClass.getMethod("labels");
                            colArrayItemMap.put("_id", getId.invoke(colItemObj));
                            colArrayItemMap.put("_labels", getLabels.invoke(colItemObj));
                            colArrayItemMap.putAll((Map<? extends String, ?>) asMap.invoke(colItemObj));
                        } else {
                            colArrayItemMap.put("_raw", columnArrayValues[iTmp]);
                        }
                        objectValue.add(colArrayItemMap);
                    }
                    ((Map) entity).put(propertyName, objectValue);
                } else {
                    ((Map) entity).put(propertyName, columnObject);
                }
```

Such queries are generated by such cypher statements.Such queries are generated by such cypher statements.

```
MATCH
  (input:Input),
  (output:Output)
WITH input, output
MATCH
  (input)-[:INPUT*1]->(in),
  (out)-[:OUTPUT*1]->(output),
  g = (in)-[connect:CONNECT*0..5]->(out)
RETURN
  input, output, extract(x IN nodes(g)|x) as nodes
```

Answer (score 1):

It was for different class loaders that we can not identify with the instanceof operator.Since the jdbc driver was placed in Tomcat / lib, it was judged to be different from the class loaded by the application.

In any case, it will be provided by converting List to List or until getResults() is supported as the return value of getArray() It is thought that it is necessary to write.